# relation " " does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I am creating a project in django using postgresql database. When I run my server the page returns the error

```
relation "backtest_trade" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "backtest_trade" ("pos", "neg", "profit", "trans...
```

when i try to save my model in the database using back.save(), where back is a variable of the model. I have registered the model in models.py of my app.

I understand that there is no table being created in the database but my understanding is that admin.register should do it. I tried looking up but none of the questions asked was able to help me.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


# Create your models here.
class trade(models.Model):

    pos = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    neg = models.IntegerField(default = 0) 
    profit = models.IntegerField(default = 0) 
    transaction = ArrayField(models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 3, max_digits= 9,default= 0), default = list)
    investment = ArrayField(models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 3, max_digits= 9,default = 0), default = list)
    sell = ArrayField(models.DecimalField(decimal_places = 3, max_digits= 9, default = 0), default = list)
    entry_date = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 20, default=''), default = list )
    exit_date = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = ''),default = list)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = "hello")

admin.site.register(trade)
```

EDIT: I have tried running makemigrations and migrate

Comment: maybe because you havent migrated you database properly, and the table trade doesnt exist, and as you have registered with admin, django wants to load it admin but cant as the table doesnt exist, thus the error

Comment: how should I add the table? Actually I imported the code from a different system and there I didn't face this problem. I did run python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate

Comment: from terminal run `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate` then run server again

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. I had to migrate the particular app in which my model was present.
After running

```
python manage.py makemigrations backtest
```

where backtest is the app, I got some error but the table was created in the database